# jQueryMP is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mvc-mini-profiler

I had the same issue when trying to run my project with mini-profiler using IIS and Google Chrome like described in [Running MiniProfiler with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304611/running-miniprofiler-with-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-set-to-false). I didn't change `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` setting, just added

```
<handlers>
    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

to `web.config`. Now after trying to run site I receive `jQueryMP is undefined`. What can I do to fix this?

Google Chrome developer toolbar shows me that error occurs in includes.js

I have MiniProfiler v 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I changed jQuery version used in my app to 1.7.1 and then called `MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()` as `MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes(null, null, null, null, null, true, false)` so profiler will use my jquery overt its.