# Can't get to first base with MiniProfiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, mvc-mini-profiler

I have read all the posts I can find and looked at a couple tutorials but haven't made it past go.

1. Installed MiniProfiler MVC and EF6
2. Added `MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();` to `Global.asax Application_Start()`
3. Added MiniProfiler.Start(); to the protected void Application_BeginRequest() method in Global.asax.
4. Added the following to my _Layout page

   ```
   <div class="row">
       @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
   </div>
   ```
5. Wrapped the method call I want to profile, thusly:

   ```
   var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
   using (profiler.Step("Saving changes"))
   {
       eventId = _calendarRepository.AddUpdateCalendarEvent(eventDto);
   }
   ```
6. For good measure, though I shouldn't need to, added the MiniProfiler handler to the web.config system.webserver section.

Everything executes fine but MiniProfiler is nowhere to be found. Tried in Chrome and IE, the div I placed `@MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()` in is empty when I view the browser source.

I'm trying to profile a `dbContext.SaveChanges()` call - I need to see the SQL EF is generating.

Thanks

Comment: How did you install MiniProfiler? Did you use the NuGet package? Do you have a MiniProfiler.cs file in the App_Start folder of your web project?

Comment: Yes, I installed it with NuGet but no, I don't have a MiniProfiler.cs in my App_Start folder folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any mention in your description of starting MiniProfiler up for individual requests. It would be something like this in Global.asax:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling;
...    
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal || someOtherCriteriaForTurningOnMiniProfiler)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
    } 
}
```

This is necessary in order to run MiniProfiler for any individual request.

Comment: Thanks Yaakov, I've updated my question. Yes, I have the protected void Application_BeginRequest() code in Global.asax

Answer (score -1):

Here is a related post that might solve your problem.  You need to have the handler registered in your web.config file

[MiniProfiler cannot find jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212725/miniprofiler-cannot-find-jquery)