# MVC-Mini-Profiler - Web Forms - 'MiniProfiler' is undefined

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I tired to install the MiniProfiler, using the HowTo on http://miniprofiler.com/

This seems to work:

```
<%= StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
```

But when I start the site, I get this error message:

```
'MiniProfiler' is undefined
```

The problem is in the included MiniProfiler code:

```
 var initMp = function(){
                load('/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=6cJT7lsVkH6SxAlFpQstk1/AgtUwMUApXN3pviVvaRE=',function(){
                    MiniProfiler.init({.....
```

When I try open `http://localhost/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js?v=6cJT7lsVkH6SxAlFpQstk1/AgtUwMUApXN3pviVvaRE=` with IE I get an 404.

I even tried this Solution  [found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771911/mini-profiler-does-not-render-scripts) but it did not work for me :(

Does anybody know this problem, or know what I can do to fix that?

### **SOLUTION**

I solved the problem by adding the config section from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771911/mini-profiler-does-not-render-scripts) solution and the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" line:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule1" path="mini-profiler*.js" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule2" path="mini-profiler*.css" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule3" path="mini-profiler*.tmpl" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The "trick" was to add the line below to get the handlers to work.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of url-rewriting? Isapirewrite maybe?

Comment: No. We are just using basic asp.net, no fancy frameworks and stuff.

Comment: I see that it's loading up "localhost". Are you using IIS Express? or a local instance of IIS 7?

Comment: I am using a local instance of IIS 7

Comment: Have you seen this? http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=50#c7

Comment: I tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771911/mini-profiler-does-not-render-scripts) they provide the same soltution. But this did not work for me. 
Adding folders with the scripts looks like a dirty solution ;)

Comment: Dirty yes. Does it work? Yes. :) Otherwise wait for Sam Saffron to see this post.

Comment: Doesn't runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" have a lot of overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to avoid this issue a bit more concisely (one handler line instead of three) by adding the following to your main `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <handlers>
    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```